# What is the downtime for deleting and recreting cloudfront using AWS CDK?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am migrating AWS CDK CloudfrontWebDistribution construct to Distribution Construct but as per docs CDK will delete and recreate the distribution, I want to know how much time this whole process will take? what is the downtime I will have?

docs for reference -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudfront-readme.html#migrating-from-the-original-cloudfrontwebdistribution-to-the-newer-distribution-construct

Comment: FYI you can avoid the replacement by overriding the logical ID.

Comment: Thank you @gshpychka, that is the alternative I have already considered, was trying to look for simple solution if i could figure out downtime time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downtime can be anywhere from minutes to hours. It all depends on the how your clients use the CloudFront distribution.

I'd recommend proceeding in the following steps:

1. Create a brand new distribution, using your new CDK constructs. Keep the old one running.
2. Swap the DNS name used by your clients. And wait for them to be updated
3. Kill the old distribution